# Select polygons that overlap with other polygons within a single feature class

Tags: python, performance, arcpy

I am running a script to identify polygons that overlap with other polygons within the same layer. I have managed to do this with the code below but the problem is that it is very slow (about 3 seconds per feature).

Is there anything I can do to improve its performance?

```
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("results.gdb", "Overlapping_Polygons", "POLYGON", "lyr_existing_cadastre", "DISABLED", "DISABLED", arcpy.Describe("lyr_existing_cadastre").spatialReference)

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("results.gdb/Overlapping_Polygons", "lyr_Overlapping_Polygons")

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("results.gdb", "Remaining_Polygons", "POLYGON", "lyr_existing_cadastre", "DISABLED", "DISABLED", arcpy.Describe("lyr_existing_cadastre").spatialReference)

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("results.gdb/Remaining_Polygons", "lyr_Remaining_Polygons")

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("in_memory", "row", "POLYGON", "lyr_existing_cadastre", "DISABLED", "DISABLED", arcpy.Describe("lyr_existing_cadastre").spatialReference)

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("row", "lyr_row")

arcpy.AddSpatialIndex_management("lyr_existing_cadastre")

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("lyr_existing_cadastre", ["OBJECTID"]) as search_cursor:
    for row in search_cursor:
        log("\t {}".format(row[0]))
        # Get the OBJECTID of row and use it to select row
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr_existing_cadastre", "NEW_SELECTION", "\"OBJECTID\" = " + str(row[0]))

        # Copy row into a new feature class called row
        arcpy.Append_management("lyr_existing_cadastre", "lyr_row", "NO_TEST")

        # Remove row from the input
        arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management("lyr_existing_cadastre")

        # Select all features that intersect with row and copy them into the row feature class
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("lyr_existing_cadastre", "WITHIN", "lyr_row", selection_type="NEW_SELECTION")
        arcpy.Append_management("lyr_existing_cadastre", "lyr_row", "NO_TEST")

        # If there is more than one feature in the row feature class
        # meaning there was something else in addition to row then delete those overlaps
        # from the input and append everything in row into the output feature class
        if (int(arcpy.GetCount_management("lyr_row").getOutput(0)) > 1):
            arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management("lyr_existing_cadastre")
            arcpy.Append_management("lyr_row", "lyr_Overlapping_Polygons", "NO_TEST")
        else:
            arcpy.Append_management("lyr_row", "lyr_Remaining_Polygons", "NO_TEST")

        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr_existing_cadastre", "CLEAR_SELECTION")
        arcpy.TruncateTable_management("lyr_row")
del search_cursor
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Thank you. I have made the edits. I hope it's better now.